# Need help in django is_valid()

Tags: python, django

I have to get the title information when the issue is failed. i.e when it goes to the else loop.

```
if title:
    title = OrgChartTitle.objects.get(pk=title)

if request.POST:
    form = OrgChartTitleForm(request.POST, instance=title )

if form.is_valid(): 
     ---
else:
   form.title = title
```

Output:

form.title should be have the value. But I am getting error like

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'
```

Comment: On what condition does the loop go inside the else?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, if the request method is not POST, then the form object does not get initialized. Thats why you are getting this error.

Make sure you check for `is_valid()` only if the form object is initialized.

Comment: I want to reuse the 'form' object. Is it possible ??    When it fails the if condition the same I have to reuse it in else as a statement.

Comment: @Vasanth You can put the is_valid function inside the request.POST and initialize a new form object in the else part